# Javascript include not working

Tags: javascript, html, apache, webserver, zpanel

I just have just bought a VPS and installed it with Zpanel, Apache, Mysql and so on. After i've uploaded my website to the server, it won't run any of my javascript.

It works fine on my other server, but not on this one. I don't even get a error in the "Console" via Google Chrome's F12. It's feels like the browser dosen't even load the javascripts.. What could be wrong? Something with the apache settings?

URL: http://test.teamcms.dk/index.php

Comment: Javascript include: https://pastebin.com/azPVaBwL

Comment: The page source served  by opening http://test.teamcms.dk/index.php does not include any script tags. Should it?

Comment: Yes.. In my index.php, there are A LOT of scripts included... Lok here at alle my scripts : https://pastebin.com/azPVaBwL

Comment: The pastbin show what you want, not why it's not there. I suggest edit the question to show the PHP server source that is supposed to generate the script tags but is not doing so, and maybe someone will be able to help you.